# tikz arrow drawing to the left side of a node

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

Hi i try to connect 2 nodes with an arrow. The arrow should end at the west of the second node.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[text=black, fill = green, text width =3cm, scale=0.5] at (1,2)(t1){Access Port mit VLAN 2050};
    \node at (2,-1) (SW1) {\includegraphics[height=3ex]{Bilder/switch.png}};
    \draw[black, thick, ->]  (t1) --  (SW1.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

with this code the arrow ends a little left to the node not directly at the left corner of the node.
is there any way?

Answer (score 8):

Thre options (I wasn't sure if "west" in your question meant the `west` anchor or the `north west` one so my example covers both):

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\node[text=black, fill = green, text width =3cm, scale=0.5] at (1,2)(t1){Access Port mit VLAN 2050}; 
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (2,-1) (SW1) {\includegraphics[height=3ex]{Bilder/switch.png}}; 
\draw[black, thick, ->] 
  (t1.west) -- ++(-40pt,0pt) |- (SW1.west); 
\draw[red, thick, ->] 
  (t1.south) -- ++(0,-30pt) -- ++(-55pt,0pt) |- (SW1.west); 
\draw[cyan, thick, ->] 
  (t1) -- (SW1.north west); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The problem is with the `inner sep` in the node containing the image. Kill this `inner sep`. Don't use the `demo` option for graphicx in your actual code (it replaces actual images with black rectangles).